# How to assign different ID's to elements in repeater?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, ado.net, repeater

I have two controls and one LinqDataSource which is inside a repeater.
LinqDataSource selects using conditions gained from first control.
Since my second element use the LinqDataSource I need to provide different ID's or otherwise data would be same for all second elements in the repeater.

Is there any way to assign different ID's or any solution to achieve my goal ?

Here is a sample code which is provided for better understanding :

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource4">
     <ItemTemplate>
         <table >
             <tr>
                 <td>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                 </td>
                 <td>
                     <asp:LinqDataSource runat="server" EntityTypeName="" ID="LinqDataSourceX" ContextTypeName="Fr.FrestandehEntities" Select="new (Value, Id)" TableName="DProperties" Where="DKey.Key == @DKeyp">
                         <WhereParameters>
                             <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" PropertyName="Text" DefaultValue="X" Name="DKeyp" Type="Object"></asp:ControlParameter>
                         </WhereParameters>
                     </asp:LinqDataSource>
                     <telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox77" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqDataSource5" DataTextField="Key" DataValueField="Key"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </table>
     </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to do this in code behind in the repeaters ItemDataBound Event. Sorry, it is in vb...

```
   Private Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound

        If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Then

            Dim lds As LinqDataSource = CType(e.Item.FindControl("RadComboBox77"), LinqDataSource)
            CType(e.Item.FindControl("RadComboBox77"), RadComboBox).DataSourceID = lds.ID

        End If


    End Sub
```

I used a C# converter tool for this so I don't know how accurate it is.

```
private void Repeater1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    if (((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem) 
                || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item))) {
        LinqDataSource lds = ((LinqDataSource)(e.Item.FindControl("RadComboBox77")));
        ((RadComboBox)(e.Item.FindControl("RadComboBox77"))).DataSourceID = lds.ID;
    }
}
```

Comment: Marked as answer unless I found a better answer. thank you ;)